# use webpack plugin with Mocha tests

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocha.js

I've used create-react-app to create an app, and ejected the config. In `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js`, I've configured the  `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` like so:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(.*)CUSTOMER(\.*)/, function(resource) {
  const customerName = process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOMER;
  resource.request = resource.request.replace(/CUSTOMER/, customerName);
})
```

The purpose of this is to replace imports such as

```
import config from '../config/customer/CUSTOMER';
```

with

```
import config from '../config/customer/foo';
```

when the value of the `REACT_APP_CUSTOMER` variable is set to "foo".

This works fine when the app runs, but I have some Mocha tests that are run via a `test-mocha` script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "test-mocha": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha --require babel-register --recursive test"
}
```

When this test runs, the import replacement doesn't happen. It seems either of the following would solve the problem:

- configure the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to be used when the tests are run
- find a way to provide a mock for `config` when the tests are run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I settled on a simple/obvious solution:

Create a dummy file `config/customer/CUSTOMER.js` that contains the minimum expected configuration, e.g.

```
export default {
  customerName: 'Dummy'
}
```

when the tests are run, an import such as

```
import config from '../config/customer/CUSTOMER';
```

will no longer fail because this module now exists.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [mocha-webpack](https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack). As mentioned in the docs, it basically runs `webpack test.js output.js && mocha output.js` with some optimizations. So, after `npm i -D mocha-webpack`, your `scripts` should look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "test-mocha": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha-webpack --recursive test"
}
```

---

Another option you could try is to make use of [mock-require](https://github.com/boblauer/mock-require), which is responsible for mocking `node.js` modules. In your case you'll need to require `mock-helper.js`:

`"test-mocha": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r ./test/mock-helper.js --recursive test"`

And `./test/mock-helper.js` should be something like:

```
const mock = require('mock-require');
const defaultCustomer = require('../config/customer/default');
const fooCustomer = require('../config/customer/foo');

const customerMock = (function () {
  switch (process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOMER) {
    case 'foo': return fooCustomer;
    default: return defaultCustomer;
  }
}())

mock('../config/customer/CUSTOMER', customerMock);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried using `mock-require` but I still get the error `Error: Cannot find module '../config/customer/CUSTOMER'`. Is `mock-require` able to mock modules that are included with `import` rather than `require`?

Comment: I've created a [repo](https://github.com/streletss/mocha-webpack-normal-module-replacement-plugin) with working example using `mock-require`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [Karmajs](https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/index.html)

Karmajs is a test runner, so you can configure it to use mocha for running tests, also you can pre-process your tests with webpack, so all the pre-processing (for `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` and any other) which was done via webpack configuration is available when you're executing tests with Karma.

Basically, Install Karma and its associated Packages in your Application

```
yarn add karma karma-chai-plugins karma-chrome-launcher karma-cli karma-coverage karma-mocha karma-mocha-reporter karma-sinon-chai karma-sourcemap-loader karma-webpack
```

Create **`karma.conf.js`**

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
const webpack = require('webpack');
webpackConfig.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'es6-promise': 'es6-promise',
  }),
];

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: [ 'Chrome' ],
    // karma only needs to know about the test bundle
    files: [
      '../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
      'karma.globals.js',
      'tests.bundle.js',
    ],
    frameworks: [ 'chai', 'mocha' ],
    // run the bundle through the webpack and sourcemap plugins
    preprocessors: {
      'tests.bundle.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ],
    },
    // reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage' ],
    reporters: [ 'mocha' ],
    // coverageReporter: {
    //   type: 'text-summary',
    //   includeAllSources: true
    // },
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatch: true,
    // webpack config object
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
    },
  });
};
```

Create `tests.bundle.js` for running tests for all your test files, in this example, all our tests files have a file extension `.spec.js` and are located inside `./src` directory.

**`tests.bundle.js`**

```
const context = require.context('./src', true, /\.spec\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);

export default context;
```

For setting up Global variables which need to be available across all your app/tests can be set with `karma.globals.js` file.

**`karma.globals.js`**

```
const __DEV__ = false;

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: 'My App',
  version: 'v2.5.6'
};
```

Once the above is configured, you can run all your tests from the directory where you have created karma.config.js and package.json by executing the following command.

```
yarn karma start
```

Note: Tests can be configured to execute in Headless Browsers (like phantomjs) as well, in this example we are using Chrome Browser to run our tests.

Answer (score -2):

You can add this to your test script:

```
REACT_APP_CUSTOMER=foo
```

So your test script becomes:

```
"test-mocha": "NODE_ENV=test REACT_APP_CUSTOMER=foo node_modules/.bin/mocha --require babel-register --recursive test"
```

This will work because it sets the value you want in your `process.env`,
and I'm not sure but I think this is the only reasonable way because you are mocking your environment when running a test.

Comment: In order for the import replacement to work, the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` needs to be enabled and the `REACT_APP_CUSTOMER` variable needs to be set. This only does the latter.

Comment: @Dónal I think you can use [mocha-webpack](https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack#readme).

as it says in its documentation it prebuilds your test files with your webpack config, so the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` would be enabled in your tests because they are build with your own config files